# Retain pin coordinates in calloutAccessoryControlTapped action

Tags: iphone, mapkit

Can I retain pin coordinates for an calloutAccessoryControlTapped action? I want to retain those coordinates to the next view. When you tap a pin, and subsequently go to the next view, i want to use the pin coordinates again. How do I retain those coordinates from that pin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` method, you can access the annotation tapped using `view.annotation` and the coordinates will be in `view.annotation.coordinate`.

You can add a property of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to the next view and set it equal to `view.annotation.coordinate`.

Answer (score 2):

Ask the `MKMapView` for its `selectedAnnotations`.  As there can only be one, and this will be the one showing a callout, you can take the coordinate in your `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` method.